# how to Run an JAVA class from WSO2 through Class mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

i read [this tutorial](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/class-Mediator/) for call a JAVA class through a Class mediator from WSO2 Integration Studio but i have any questions; for call the JAVA Class need put the class in a specified directory? or i must compile it a JAR file and export it like a Library in my WSO2 Integration Studio enviroment server? ok assuming that the class was put in the correct directory in the correct way (.cass or .jar), how to compile the example JAVA code??? why this dont have Main Method and i when try compile it the JAVA Compiler not allow to me.
The JAVA code showed in the wso2 oficial web site example is the next:

```
package samples.mediators;

    import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
    import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;
    import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement;
    import org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory;
    import org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory;
    import org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFactory;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

    import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

    public class SimpleClassMediator extends AbstractMediator {

        private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SimpleClassMediator.class);

        private String variable1="10";

        private String variable2="10";

        private int variable3=0;

        public SimpleClassMediator(){}

        public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {
            // Do somthing useful..
            // Note the access to the Synapse Message context
            return true;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return null;
        }

        public void setTraceState(int traceState) {
            traceState = 0;
        }

        public int getTraceState() {
            return 0;
        }

        public void setVariable1(String newValue) {
            variable1=newValue;
        }

        public String getVariable1() {
            return variable1;
        }

        public void setVariable2(String newValue){
            variable2=newValue;
        }

        public String getVariable2(){
            return variable2;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Custom Mediator Project in Integration Studio and pack it with Car app. Take a look at [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/customizations/creating-custom-mediators/) document.

Comment: i was can solved it with this info, thanks, perfect!